# Chrome rubymine server log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, rubymine

When i start typing `localhost:3000/` in the chrome address bar it starts the GET request to application/index before i click "Enter" button. At this moment in my server log i see

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-20 23:22:28 +0300
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ApplicationController#index as HTML
  Rendered application/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1535ms (Views: 1520.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

And then it seems my server log is dead. Everything works fine, i can browse pages in my app and all requests completes successfully, but log is empty. Also when i click on the bookmark `localhost:3000` the problem doesn't go away. With Mozilla i have no such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome uses prefetch (prerendering) function to load the page before you explicitly visit it. Chrome's behaviour may vary from version to version, but to recommend browser stop prefetching page make sure you don't have those tags in the code:

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="...">

<link rel="prerender" href="...">
```

Wikipedia explains more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_prefetching). It is probably would be difficult to turn prefetching off in Chrome but Mozilla (however you don't have problem with) recommend to try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Controlling_DNS_prefetching):

```
<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off">
```